# Пустые поля из формы. Проблема решена

Tags: php, html, html-form

Спасибо кто откликнулся. Проблему решила. В моем случае, нужно было просто к каждому элементу добавить value="" с описанием.

Ситуация такая. Есть многостраничная форма, еле как в интернете нашла. Все бы хорошо, единственная проблема это пустые поля, либо "name" которые были заданы. Подскажите в чем ошибка.

```js
     <?php
 
  if (isset($_POST['stroim'])) {$stroim = $_POST['stroim'];}

if (isset($_POST['plo'])) {$plo = $_POST['plo'];}

if (isset($_POST['ytag'])) {$ytag = $_POST['ytag'];};

if (isset($_POST['material'])) {$material = $_POST['material)'];}

if (isset($_POST['completaci'])) {$completaci = $_POST['completaci)'];}

if (isset($_POST['object'])) {$object = $_POST['object)'];}

if (isset($_POST['stroika'])) {$stroika = $_POST['stroika)'];}

 if (isset($_POST['budget'])) {$budget = $_POST['budget)'];}
    
    $to = ""; //укажите ваш адрес
    $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset = UTF-8";
    $subject = "Сообщение с вашего сайта";
    $message = "Имя пославшего: $stroim \nЭлектронный адрес: $plo \nСообщение: $ytag \nМатериал: $material \nКомплектация: $completaci \nОбъект: $object \nСтройка: $stroika \nБюджет: $budget";
    $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($send == 'true')
    {
    echo "<b>Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!<p>";
echo "<a href=index3.html>Нажмите,</a> чтобы вернуться на главную страницу";
}

    else
    {
    echo "<p><b>Сообщение не отправлено. Приносим свои извинения.";
    echo "<p><b>Попробуйте повторить отправку позже";
    }
    ?>
```

```html
<div class="q-num">Вопрос 5 из 8</div>
        <form   method="post" action="object.php">
        <textarea style="display:none;" name="stroim">
          <?php
         if (isset($_POST['stroim'])) {$stroim = $_POST['stroim'];}
          echo "$stroim";

          ?>
        </textarea>
        <textarea style="display:none;" name="plo">
          <?php
          if (isset($_POST['plo'])) {$plo = $_POST['plo'];}

          echo "$plo";
          ?>
        </textarea>
        <textarea style="display:none;" name="ytag">
         <?php
         if (isset($_POST['ytag'])) {$ytag = $_POST['ytag'];}
          echo "$ytag";
          ?>
        </textarea>
        <textarea style="display:none;" name="material">
         <?php
          if (isset($_POST['material'])) {$material = $_POST['material)'];}
          echo "$material";
          ?>
        </textarea>
        <div class="item-title item-6-title">Комплектация</div>
        <label><input type="radio" id="radio 17" name="completaci">Сруб</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" id="radio 18" name="completaci">Сруб+фундамент</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" id="radio 19" name="completaci">Сруб+фундамент+кровля</label><br>
        <input class="send" type="submit" value=Далее> 
        </form>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Проверку лучше сделать вот такую (более гибкий вариант):

```
$stroim = isset($_POST["stroim"]) ? $_POST["stroim"] : "";
```

2) Вставку текста в поле лучше сделать так:

```
<textarea><?= $stroim; ?></textarea>
```

(Не забудьте сохранить все необходимые атрибуты .)
3) Относительно отправки письма:

```
if (mail(...)) {...}
```

Я к тому, что сохранять результат отправки письма в переменной нет смысла. Да и сравнение

```
if ($send == "true") {...}
```

Зачем так усложнять? Если нужно строгое равенство с true, то

```
if ($send === true) {...}
```

Если не важно, то есть за истину принимаем все, что можно преобразовать в true, то просто достаточно

```
if ($send) {...}
```

Comment: И не стоит забывать экранировать.

Если переменные служат только для передачи в шаблон, то можно обработать их сразу в коде:
`$stroim = isset($_POST["stroim"]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["stroim"]) : "";`

Если используются где-то ещё, то непосредственно при выводе:
`<textarea><?= htmlspecialchars($stroim); ?></textarea>`

Но, не оба варианта сразу.

Comment: Правильно. Я решил опустить проверку данных, так как она вопроса не касается, но без этого никуда. Если используются ограниченные диапазоны данных, то не помешает подумать о доменах (списках допустимых значений). В интернете найдете много таких решений. Если нужно, объясню лично ;)

Comment: А где здесь лично можно поговорить?) Принцип я поняла ,но хотела бы удостовериться, что все верно поняла.)

Comment: bogdan_balov (Skype).

Comment: @Vitaly все равно на почту пустые поля приходят. Пыталась сделать, как вы написали и как Богдан. Результата ноль.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо $message установить заглушку - произвольную строку. Если придет все правильно, нужно искать проблему в тексте сообщения.

Comment: Описанное выше не удаляет пустые поля, а гарантирует, что переменная будет существовать и её содержимое не поломает работу сайта. Если пользователь просто нажмёт на Submit, то, конечно, придут пустые поля. Для того, чтобы не было пустых полей, нужно дополнительно валидировать и значения. При пустых значениях заново возвращать форму с уже ведёнными значениями и сообщение(ями) об ошибке. В данном случае - пустом значении.

Comment: @B.Bohdan Cделала как вы сказали, пришло сообщение, но полностью пустое. Т.е никак раньше. Потом решила поменять кавычки в значение message. До этого были такие "" а поменяла на такие '' и пришло сообщение такого характера.
Что строим?: $stroitsy \nУкажите площадь: $plo \nЭтажность: $ytag \nМатериал: $material \nКомплектация: $completaci \nОбъект: $object \nСтройка: $stroika \nБюджет: $budget
Получается. Заместо них нужно вставлять type? (text, radio,chekbox)